# Bounding box doesn't rotate when the sprite rotates

Tags: java, rotation, sprite, bounding-box

Working on a simple Java 2D game. A tank is controlled by the user. It can be rotated in any angle, and it moves in the direction of that angle.

I'm making a bounding box for the tank, so later I can add collision detection. Currently, I have the box following the sprite wherever it goes, but it doesn't rotate when the sprite rotates. I tried to add code to make the box rotate with the sprite, but adding this code simply makes the bounding box go crazy. It doesn't appear as a box anymore, more like a line just flickering and moving around.

*(Obviously the bounding box should be invisible, but for now I'm drawing it on the screen to check for problems).*

`xcoo[]` and `ycoo[]` are both of type `double` and hold four values each. These values are the coordinates of the four vertices of the bounding box (a rectangle-shaped `Path2D`).

*(Please note that an actual bounding box is only created when it needs to be drawn on the screen, or in collision detection which I haven't written yet. Most of the time, it's just coordinates.)*

The Tank's `move()` method is called every cycle of the game-loop.

The `move()` method updates the location of the sprite, and the location of the bounding box. This works fine. But as I said, trying to rotate the bounding box in that method (aka manipulate it's vertices using the rotation matrix), makes it go

Here is the `Tank`'s `move()` method:

```
public void move(){

    // Updates the location of the sprite. (works)
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    bbCenterX += dx;
    bbCenterY += dy;

    // Updates the location of the bounding box. (works)    
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        xcoo[i] += dx;
        ycoo[i] += dy;
    } 

    // Should rotate the bounding box (aka, manipulate it's coordinates
    // so when it is created with these coordinates, it's rotated).
    // (Doesn't work).
    for(int z=0;z<4;z++){

        xcoo[z] = xcoo[z] - bbCenterX;
        ycoo[z] = ycoo[z] - bbCenterY;

        xcoo[z] = ((xcoo[z] * Math.cos(angle)) - (ycoo[z] * Math.sin(angle)));
        ycoo[z] = ((xcoo[z] * Math.sin(angle)) + (ycoo[z] * Math.cos(angle)));

        xcoo[z] = xcoo[z] + bbCenterX;
        ycoo[z] = ycoo[z] + bbCenterY;

    }

}
```

What's wrong with my rotation? I suspect that that's the part of the code where the problem is, but if you think differently, please tell me to post more code.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Reminds me of a story my commercial artist uncle told me ca 1970.  He was working on a TV commercial (for trucks) with some of the earliest computer graphics.  The geeks first had the truck wheels rolling onto the screen, then the truck body descended onto the wheels.  Then the wheels rolled away, leaving (oops!) the truck body standing there.  They got it right on the second take.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title of your question - *Bounding box doesn't rotate when the sprite rotates*

In computer graphics the most common implementation of a bounding box is the [Axis-aligned minimum bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box#Axis-aligned_minimum_bounding_box) which obviously will not rotate when you rotate your sprite because it is *axis aligned*.

I am not aware of what implementation the `Java 2D` package you are using implements but it certainly sound like this and not an [Arbitrarily oriented minimum bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box#Arbitrarily_oriented_minimum_bounding_box) as you hoped.

Perhaps the rendering of your bounding box somehow assumes that it is `axis-aligned` and therefore fails to render when you present it with a box that is not `axis-aligned`.

Comment: No, sadly I need the bounding box to rotate, since the sprite has to rotate and the bounding box has to contain all of the sprite and only the sprite. I wish I could make it an axis-aligned rectangle, it would make things much easier for me.
When you look at my rotation code, do you see anything problematic?